# e.target.value in button returns undefined sometimes. Why this happens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined four buttons and those buttons will call same method in onClick event.

**Method**

```
   changeFilterForButtons(e){
    let filter = e.target.value;
    console.log("----------------------------"  + filter);
    this.props.handleData(filter);
    this.props.filterData();
}
```

**Render()**

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div className='audit-menu' style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
            <div className='row align-items-center'>
                <div className="col text-left ml-2 font-weight-bold">
                    Invoice audit
                </div>
                <div className="col-6 ">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group w-100">
                        <button class="w-25 btn menu-btn" value='inbox' onClick={this.changeFilterForButtons.bind(this)}><i className="icon-upload pr-3">
                        </i>Inbox
                        </button>
                        <button class="w-25 btn menu-btn" value='rejected'  onClick={this.changeFilterForButtons.bind(this)}><i className="icon-search pr-3">
                        </i>Rejected
                        </button>
                        <button class="w-25 btn menu-btn" value='accepted' onClick={this.changeFilterForButtons.bind(this)}><i className="icon-search pr-3">
                        </i>Accepted
                        </button>
                        <button class="w-25 btn menu-btn" value='archive' onClick={this.changeFilterForButtons.bind(this)}><i className="icon-search pr-3">
                        </i>Archive
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    ​
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown d-none d-lg-block">
                        <a aria-expanded="true" className="nav-link dropdown-toggle select-company-dropdown"
                           data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="selectLanguage">Select company</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When buttons are clicked most of the times *e.target.value* is taken by above function. But sometimes it returns **undefined**. Why this is happening ?. Console.log output is added below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
this.changeFilterForButtons
```

instead of

```
this.changeFilterForButtons.bind(this)
```

or in constructor :

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.changeFilterForButtons = this.changeFilterForButtons.bind(this);
}
```

you can look this article to more information about bind, this

[This is why we need to bind event](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb)

Comment: Your answer is very useful. I changed the code according to your changes. but i am still getting same error. This is only happening sometimes not every time. Can all the buttons be called into one method?.

Comment: I try without this.props.handleData(filter); and this.props.filterData(); . It's still work all time

Comment: your answer is correct. my error was with it's icon, when i click the icon it returns undefined.

Comment: Glad to hear if it helps you, please accept the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

First I must say that both below answers are correct. My error occurred because of it's icon.

```
<button class="w-25 btn menu-btn" value='archive' onClick={this.changeFilterForButtons.bind(this)}><i className="icon-search pr-3"</i>Archive</button>
```

> When i accidentally click the icon, it will return undefined because it doesn't have any value to return.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble. When I read the second comment I saw where to find the solution.

CSS solution:

```
button > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/slightly-careful-sub-elements-clickable-things/)